# Assign Integer to Each Turing Machine

Tags: elementary-set-theory, formal-languages, automata, turing-machines

I have the following problem: suppose that we have an infinite set of symbols, $A = \{a_1, a_2, ...\}$ from which all Turing Machine input alphabets are chosen.  Show how we could assign an integer to all Turing Machines that had a finite subset of these symbols as its input alphabet.

It seems to me that the set of all finite subsets of $A$ is the power set of $A$.  But $P(A)$ is uncountable so I wouldn't be able to assign an integer to all Turing Machines that had an input alphabet in $P(A)$.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set of all *finite* subsets of an infinite set is *not* its power set. For example, the set of all even numbers is in $\mathcal P(\Bbb Z)$, but it is not a finite subset of $\Bbb Z$.

The set of all finite subsets of a *countable* set is countable. Can you see why?

Comment: Well, each finite subset is countable.  And the set of all finite subsets is countable because it's a countable union of countable sets.  To answer the original question, where $B$ is the set of all finite subsets of $A$, I can define $f: N \to B$ where $f$ is a bijection.  Then for each Turing Machine whose input alphabet, $b \in B$, we know that there exists some $n \in N$ such that $f(n) = b$.  Thus we have assigned each Turing Machine an integer.  Is this correct?

Comment: @user93189, yes, that is one way to prove that the set of all finite subsets of a countable set is countable, but you used the countable union condition, a weak form of the axiom of choice, when you actually didn't need to. Can you work out a way to do it constructively by actually coming up with a way to count them? As for the Turing machines, you're not there yet. A Turing machine is not determined just by its alphabet--there are all those rules too.